# Show Progress Bar when Inserting the value in Database Asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to show progress bar when I click on insert/update button as buttons have some validations/updation/insertion functions due to this I am unable to calculate time of particular button click process. Here is my code.

```
try
    {            
        dt = myDbGL.SelectQuery("Select ComCreationDate from GASCompanyDetail where ComCode = '" + DropDownCompany.SelectedItem.Value + "' And ComCreationDate is not NULL");
        if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            DateTime ComDate = DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["ComCreationDate"].ToString());
            DateTime TRDate = DateTime.Parse(TB_TRDate.Text);
            DateTime GLDate = DateTime.Parse(TB_GLDate.Text);
            int result = DateTime.Compare(TRDate, ComDate);
            if (result < 0)
            {
                DisplayMessage = "Transaction Date is not less then to Company Creation Date!";
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "alert('" + DisplayMessage + "');", true); return;
            }
            result = DateTime.Compare(GLDate, ComDate);
            if (result < 0)
            {
                DisplayMessage = "GL Date is not less then to Company Creation Date!";
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "alert('" + DisplayMessage + "');", true); return;
            }
        }

        GridTotal();

        dt = myDbGL.SelectQuery("Select * from GLSBankAccountDetailView where AccCode = '" + DropDownType.SelectedItem.Value + "'");
        if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            ChequeBankName = ""; // dt.Rows[0]["BankName"].ToString();
            ChequeBranchName = ""; // dt.Rows[0]["BranchName"].ToString();
            ChequeAccountNo = dt.Rows[0]["BacAccountNumber"].ToString();
        }

        TRTotalAmount = 0;
        TRTotalAmount = myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(TB_TRTotalAmount.Text);
        if (TRTotalAmount < 0)
        {
            DisplayMessage = "Cannot Save Negative Transaction!";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "alert('" + DisplayMessage + "');", true);
            return;
        }
        ExchangeRate = myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(TB_TRExchangeRate.Text);
        if (ExchangeRate == 0)
        {
            DisplayMessage = "Please enter valid Exchange Rate!";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "alert('" + DisplayMessage + "');", true);
            return;
        }

        dt = myDbGL.SelectQuery("Select EntryFrom from GLTLedger where TRNo = '" + TB_TRCode_Hidden.Text + "' And EntryFrom = 'Payment Detail'");
        if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            DisplayMessage = "This Transaction is not related to this Entry Form";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "alert('" + DisplayMessage + "');", true);
            return;
        }

        dt = myDbGL.SelectQuery("Select EnterBy, EnterDate from GLTPaymentMaster where TRNo = '" + TB_TRCode_Hidden.Text + "'");
        if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            EnterBy = dt.Rows[0]["EnterBy"].ToString();
            EnterDate = dt.Rows[0]["EnterDate"].ToString();
        }

        if (TB_TRCode.Text.Left(2) == "BP") { VoucherType = "BANK"; } else { VoucherType = "CASH"; }
        if (CB_Reverse.Checked) { ReverseDateCheck = TB_ReverseDate.Text; } else { ReverseDateCheck = null; }

        if (!CB_Reverse.Checked)
        {
            dt = myDbGL.SelectQuery("Select TRPostStatus, TRPostStatusReverse from GLTLedger where TRNo = '" + TB_TRCode_Hidden.Text + "' And (TRPostStatusReverse = 'UN-POST')");
            if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                myDbGL.deleteTable("Delete from GLTLedger where TRNo = '" + TB_TRCode_Hidden.Text + "' And TRReverseStatus = 1");
                myDbGL.UpdatePaymentMaster(TB_TRCode_Hidden.Text, CB_Reverse.Checked.ToString(), ReverseDateCheck, EnterBy.ToString(), EnterDate.ToString(), LoginUserID.ToString(), myDbGL.GetServerDateTime());
            }
            dt = myDbGL.SelectQuery("Select TRPostStatus, TRPostStatusReverse from GLTLedger where TRNo = '" + TB_TRCode_Hidden.Text + "' And (TRPostStatus = 'POST')");
            if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                DisplayMessage = "Cannot Change Posted Transaction!";
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "alert('" + DisplayMessage + "');", true);
                return;
            }
            dt = myDbGL.SelectQuery("Select TRPostStatus, TRPostStatusReverse from GLTLedger where TRNo = '" + TB_TRCode_Hidden.Text + "' And (TRPostStatusReverse = 'POST')");
            if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                DisplayMessage = "Cannot Change Posted Transaction!";
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "alert('" + DisplayMessage + "');", true);
                return;
            }                
        }

        TRApprovedLevel = 0; TRCurrentLevel = 0; TRUserLevel = 0;
        dt = myDbGL.SelectQuery("Select PagWebAddress from UMSPageDetail where PagWebAddress like '%" + Path.GetFileName(Request.PhysicalPath) + "%' And PagApprove = 'True'");
        if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            dt1 = myDbGL.SelectQuery("Select * from GLTPostingDetail where PosPageName not like '%Reverse%' And PosPageWebAddress like '" + Path.GetFileName(Request.PhysicalPath) + "'");
            if (dt1.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                dt2 = myDbGL.SelectQuery("Select TOP (1) ApvSerialNo from GASApprovalPolicyDetailView where ApvTType = '" + dt1.Rows[0]["PosPageName"].ToString() + "' And SitCode like '" + LoginUserIDSitCode.ToString() + "' Order by ApvSerialNo Desc");
                if (dt2.Rows.Count != 0) { TRApprovedLevel = myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(dt2.Rows[0]["ApvSerialNo"].ToString()); }

                dt2 = myDbGL.SelectQuery("Select TOP (1) ApvSerialNo from GASApprovalPolicyDetailView where ApvTType = '" + dt1.Rows[0]["PosPageName"].ToString() + "' And SitCode like '" + LoginUserIDSitCode.ToString() + "' AND UseID = '" + LoginUserID.ToString() + "' Order by ApvSerialNo Desc");
                if (dt2.Rows.Count != 0) { TRUserLevel = myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(dt2.Rows[0]["ApvSerialNo"].ToString()); }

                dt2 = myDbGL.SelectQuery("Select ApprovedLevel from [" + dt1.Rows[0]["PosTableMaster"].ToString() + "] where [" + dt1.Rows[0]["PosColumnWhereMaster"].ToString() + "] = '" + TB_TRCode.Text + "'");
                if (dt2.Rows.Count != 0) { TRCurrentLevel = myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(dt2.Rows[0]["ApprovedLevel"].ToString()); }

                if (TRApprovedLevel != 0 && TRCurrentLevel > TRUserLevel)
                {
                    DisplayMessage = "Cannot Change as This Transaction approved by Higher Authority!";
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "alert('" + DisplayMessage + "');", true); return;
                }
            }
        }

        if (CB_Reverse.Checked)
        {
            dt = myDbGL.SelectQuery("Select TRPostStatus, TRPostStatusReverse from GLTLedger where TRNo = '" + TB_TRCode_Hidden.Text + "' And (TRPostStatus <> 'POST')");
            if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                DisplayMessage = "Cannot Reverse Un-Posted Transaction!";
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "alert('" + DisplayMessage + "');", true);
                return;
            }
            dt = myDbGL.SelectQuery("Select TRPostStatus, TRPostStatusReverse from GLTLedger where TRNo = '" + TB_TRCode_Hidden.Text + "' And (TRPostStatusReverse = 'POST')");
            if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                DisplayMessage = "Cannot Reverse Posted Transaction!";
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "alert('" + DisplayMessage + "');", true);
                return;
            }

            if (TB_ReverseDate.Text.ToString().Equals(""))
            {
                DisplayMessage = "Please Enter Any Reverse Date!";
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "alert('" + DisplayMessage + "');", true);
                return;
            }
            DateTime GLDate = DateTime.Parse(TB_GLDate.Text);
            DateTime ReverseDate = DateTime.Parse(TB_ReverseDate.Text);
            int result = DateTime.Compare(ReverseDate, GLDate);

            if (result < 0)
            {
                DisplayMessage = "Reverse Date is not less then/equals to GL Date. Please enter correct Reverse Date!";
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "alert('" + DisplayMessage + "');", true);
                return;
            }

            //myDbGL.deleteTable("Delete from GLTPaymentMaster where TRNo = '" + TB_TRCode_Hidden.Text + "'");
            myDbGL.deleteTable("Delete from GLTLedger where TRNo = '" + TB_TRCode_Hidden.Text + "' And TRReverseStatus = 1");

            dt = myDbGL.SelectQuery("Select * from GLTLedger where TRNo = '" + TB_TRCode_Hidden.Text + "' And TRReverseStatus = 0");
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                dt1 = myDbGL.SelectQuery("Select TRSerialNo from GLTLedger where TRNo = '" + TB_TRCode_Hidden.Text + "'");
                myDbGL.InsertLedgerDetail(dt.Rows[i]["TRNo"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRDate"].ToString(), ReverseDateCheck, dt.Rows[i]["TRType"].ToString(), "POST", "UN-POST", CB_Reverse.Checked.ToString(), ReverseDateCheck, (myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(dt1.Rows.Count.ToString()) + 1).ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRAccCode"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRRefAccCode"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRDocReference"].ToString(), myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(dt.Rows[i]["TRDocRefTotalAmount"].ToString()), myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(dt.Rows[i]["TRDocRefBalanceAmount"].ToString()), myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(dt.Rows[i]["TRCredit"].ToString()), myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(dt.Rows[i]["TRDebit"].ToString()), myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(dt.Rows[i]["TRExchangeRate"].ToString()), myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(dt.Rows[i]["TRAmountConverted"].ToString()), dt.Rows[i]["TRCurCode"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRTxsCode"].ToString(), myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(dt.Rows[i]["TRTaxPercent"].ToString()), dt.Rows[i]["TRChequeNo"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRChequeDate"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRChequeMaturityDate"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRChequeDepositDate"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRDepositNo"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRChequeBankName"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRChequeBranchName"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRChequeAccountNo"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRRefNo"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRGrpCode"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRComCode"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRBsuCode"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRCosCode"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRDepCode"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRSecCode"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRProCode"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRFucCode"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRCusAccCode"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRSupAccCode"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRConAccCode"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRAgtAccCode"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRIvtAccCode"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRInvCode"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TRRemarks"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["TREntryType"].ToString(), EnterBy.ToString(), EnterDate.ToString(), LoginUserID.ToString(), myDbGL.GetServerDateTime(), "Payment Detail", dt.Rows[i]["EntryTypeDoc"].ToString());
            }

            myDbGL.UpdatePaymentMaster(TB_TRCode_Hidden.Text, CB_Reverse.Checked.ToString(), ReverseDateCheck, EnterBy.ToString(), EnterDate.ToString(), LoginUserID.ToString(), myDbGL.GetServerDateTime());
            myDbGL.InsertUserLog("General Ledger", "Transaction", "Payment Detail", "Update", TB_TRCode.Text, LoginUserID.ToString(), myDbGL.GetUserPCName(), myDbGL.GetUserPCIP(), myDbGL.GetUserPCMAC(), myDbGL.GetServerDateTime(), myDbGL.GetServerDateTime());
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
            return;
        }

        myDbGL.deleteTable("Delete from GLTPaymentMaster where TRNo = '" + TB_TRCode_Hidden.Text + "'");
        myDbGL.deleteTable("Delete from GLTLedger where TRNo = '" + TB_TRCode_Hidden.Text + "'");
        TRTotalAmount = 0;
        TRCount = 1;
        foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in gvTransaction.Rows)
        {
            TRDebit = 0;
            TRCredit = 0;
            if (((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridAccount")).SelectedItem.Value != "-1")
            {
                if (((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridDebitCredit")).SelectedItem.Text == "DEBIT")
                {
                    TRDebit = myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("TB_TRAmountConverted")).Text);
                    TRCredit = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    TRDebit = 0;
                    TRCredit = myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("TB_TRAmountConverted")).Text);
                }
                //if (myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("TB_TRAmount")).Text) != 0 && ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridAccount")).SelectedValue.ToString() != "-1")
                if (myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("TB_TRAmountConverted")).Text) != 0)
                {
                    myDbGL.InsertLedgerDetail(TB_TRCode.Text, TB_TRDate.Text, TB_GLDate.Text, VoucherType, "UN-POST", "UN-POST", CB_Reverse.Checked.ToString(), ReverseDateCheck, TRCount.ToString(), ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridAccount")).SelectedValue.ToString(), DropDownType.SelectedItem.Value, ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridDocRef")).SelectedValue.ToString(), myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("TB_TRTotalDocAmount")).Text), myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("TB_TRTotalDocBalAmount")).Text), TRDebit, TRCredit, myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(TB_TRExchangeRate.Text), myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("TB_TRAmountConverted")).Text), DropDownCurrency.SelectedItem.Value, ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridTaxSlab")).SelectedValue.ToString(), myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("TB_TRTaxPercent")).Text), ((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("TB_TRChequeNo")).Text, ((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("TB_TRChequeDate")).Text, ((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("TB_TRChequeMaturityDate")).Text, ((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("TB_TRChequeDepositDate")).Text, "", ChequeBankName, ChequeBranchName, ChequeAccountNo, TB_TRRefNo.Text, DropDownGroup.SelectedItem.Value, DropDownCompany.SelectedItem.Value, ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridBU")).SelectedValue.ToString(), ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridCostCenter")).SelectedValue.ToString(), ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridDepartment")).SelectedValue.ToString(), ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridSection")).SelectedValue.ToString(), ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridProject")).SelectedValue.ToString(), ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridFunction")).SelectedValue.ToString(), ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridCustomer")).SelectedValue.ToString(), ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridSupplier")).SelectedValue.ToString(), ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridContractor")).SelectedValue.ToString(), ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridAgent")).SelectedValue.ToString(), ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridInvestor")).SelectedValue.ToString(), ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridItem")).SelectedValue.ToString(), ((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("TB_TRRemarks")).Text, "CHILD", EnterBy.ToString(), EnterDate.ToString(), LoginUserID.ToString(), myDbGL.GetServerDateTime(), "Payment Detail", "CHILD");
                    TRCount = TRCount + 1;
                    myDbGL.InsertLedgerDetail(TB_TRCode.Text, TB_TRDate.Text, TB_GLDate.Text, VoucherType, "UN-POST", "UN-POST", CB_Reverse.Checked.ToString(), ReverseDateCheck, TRCount.ToString(), DropDownType.SelectedItem.Value, ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridAccount")).SelectedValue.ToString(), ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridDocRef")).SelectedValue.ToString(), myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("TB_TRTotalDocAmount")).Text), myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("TB_TRTotalDocBalAmount")).Text), TRCredit, TRDebit, myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(TB_TRExchangeRate.Text), myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("TB_TRAmountConverted")).Text), DropDownCurrency.SelectedItem.Value, ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridTaxSlab")).SelectedValue.ToString(), myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("TB_TRTaxPercent")).Text), ((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("TB_TRChequeNo")).Text, ((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("TB_TRChequeDate")).Text, ((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("TB_TRChequeMaturityDate")).Text, ((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("TB_TRChequeDepositDate")).Text, "", ChequeBankName, ChequeBranchName, ChequeAccountNo, TB_TRRefNo.Text, DropDownGroup.SelectedItem.Value, DropDownCompany.SelectedItem.Value, ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridBU")).SelectedValue.ToString(), ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridCostCenter")).SelectedValue.ToString(), ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridDepartment")).SelectedValue.ToString(), ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridSection")).SelectedValue.ToString(), ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridProject")).SelectedValue.ToString(), ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridFunction")).SelectedValue.ToString(), ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridCustomer")).SelectedValue.ToString(), ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridSupplier")).SelectedValue.ToString(), ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridContractor")).SelectedValue.ToString(), ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridAgent")).SelectedValue.ToString(), ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridInvestor")).SelectedValue.ToString(), ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("DropDownGridItem")).SelectedValue.ToString(), ((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("TB_TRRemarks")).Text, "CHILD", EnterBy.ToString(), EnterDate.ToString(), LoginUserID.ToString(), myDbGL.GetServerDateTime(), "Payment Detail", "PARENT");
                    TRCount = TRCount + 1;
                }
            }
            TRTotalAmount = TRTotalAmount + (TRDebit - TRCredit);
        }
        if (TRTotalAmount != 0) { myDbGL.InsertLedgerDetail(TB_TRCode.Text, TB_TRDate.Text, TB_GLDate.Text, VoucherType, "UN-POST", "UN-POST", CB_Reverse.Checked.ToString(), ReverseDateCheck, "0", DropDownType.SelectedItem.Value, DropDownType.SelectedItem.Value, "-1", 0, 0, 0, TRTotalAmount, myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(TB_TRExchangeRate.Text), TRTotalAmount, DropDownCurrency.SelectedItem.Value, "-1", 0, "", "", "", "", "", ChequeBankName, ChequeBranchName, ChequeAccountNo, TB_TRRefNo.Text, DropDownGroup.SelectedItem.Value, DropDownCompany.SelectedItem.Value, "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", TB_Remarks.Text, "TOTAL", EnterBy.ToString(), EnterDate.ToString(), LoginUserID.ToString(), myDbGL.GetServerDateTime(), "Payment Detail", "TOTAL"); }
        if (TRTotalAmount != 0) { myDbGL.InsertPaymentMaster(TB_TRCode.Text, TB_TRDate.Text, TB_GLDate.Text, TRTotalAmount, VoucherType, DropDownType.SelectedItem.Value, DropDownType.SelectedItem.Text, TB_Remarks.Text, myDbGL.ConvertStringToNumber(TB_TRExchangeRate.Text), DropDownCurrency.SelectedItem.Value, DropDownGroup.SelectedItem.Value, DropDownCompany.SelectedItem.Value, CB_Reverse.Checked.ToString(), ReverseDateCheck, "UN-POST", "UN-POST", TRCurrentLevel, EnterBy.ToString(), EnterDate.ToString(), LoginUserID.ToString(), myDbGL.GetServerDateTime()); }
        myDbGL.InsertUserLog("General Ledger", "Transaction", "Payment Detail", "Update", TB_TRCode.Text, LoginUserID.ToString(), myDbGL.GetUserPCName(), myDbGL.GetUserPCIP(), myDbGL.GetUserPCMAC(), myDbGL.GetServerDateTime(), myDbGL.GetServerDateTime());
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        myDbGL.CatchException(this, ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `OnClientClick` event handler to add css class before server request to show infinite progress.

```
<asp:Button ID="uniqueID" ClientIdMode="Static" OnClientClick="GetData()" ... />

  function GetData() {
      $('#uniqueID').addClass('loading');
      $.ajax(...).then(function() {
          //update cell data
          $('#uniqueID').removeClass('loading');
      });
  }
```

After response comes page element will be refreshed with new data.

But to achieve client friendly solution you need to use AJAX to get data as your page will be in reloading state when use classic ASP.NET postback approaches. Use `ClientIdMode="Static"` to get control identifier on your client side.